# How to say that it rains on something?

Tags: idiom, weather

How can I say in Latin that it is raining on something?
I can find ways around like *pluvia rem tingit*, but I would like something more literally "it rains on something" than "the rain makes something wet".
Would something like *pluit super re* or *pluit in rem* work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Augustine uses *super* in the following:

> *pluit super iustos et iniustos* / it rains on the just and the unjust (*City of God*, 4.2)

However, it could be as simple as using [impluere](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=impluo&la=la#lexicon).  It's used literally of rain (e.g. Pliny, *Nat. Hist.*, 2.210) and figuratively, of punches raining down on someone, for example (Plautus, *Most.*, 871).

EDIT RE: USAGE 
The *Oxford Latin Dictionary* specifies that the dative is used in figurative phrases.  Hence the *ceteris & mi* in the Plautus example.  This must also explain the *summis silvis* in Ovid, *Met.*, 1.573 but I have to admit it doesn't seem that figurative to me (although the OLD lists it under figurative uses).

Pliny (*Nat. Hist.*, 2.210) uses *in* + accusative, in addition to *impluere*:

> *in cuius quandam aream non impluit* / into whose particular courtyard it doesn't rain

All other uses cited imply the object or *impluere* is simply used impersonally without expressing an object, so it makes it hard to extrapolate a hard and fast rule about the use of prepositions and/or the accusative.

Comment: Thanks! Could you add a note on using *impluere*? Judging by the examples in L&S, it looks like it needs a dative, not an accusative or a preposition.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I tried!  Hope it helps.